# How to fix error 'Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 100'

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string

Here is my **connection string** for locally debugging:

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=&quot;
data source=SFP;
initial catalog=POLLINATORS;
integrated security=True;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
App=EntityFramework"
```

**Partial Stack Trace:**

at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, String& keyname, String& keyvalue) at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(IDictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, IList`1 validKeywords) at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, IList`1 validKeywords) at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString) at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()

thanks for your help!
~susan~

Comment: The error says that, at character 100 of your connection string, the connection string is no longer valid. Are you saving it in multiple lines like that in your web.config? You can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the closing quotes in the provider connection string:

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=&quot;
data source=SFP;
initial catalog=POLLINATORS;
integrated security=True;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
App=EntityFramework&quot;"
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly.  However it uncovered another issue.  I will open another request.  Really appreciate you help!